# Disable Reply Email Management feature

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Does anybody know how to disable RMM feature without using "Direct forwards" in Sender profile, since we want to avoid this  unknown string similar to reply-fef61176716307-85_HTML-30795567-7237684-1@xyz.com?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable RMM entirely from Email Admin > Account Settings > Reply Mail Management and change the 'DNS Record Redirect Complete' option to 'No', (as RMM only works if DNS Record redirect is completed).