# Why does RMM still unsubscribe users?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have disabled "Unsubscribe Manual Requests" in my RMM settings and unchecked all the terms beneath it. However if I send an email to myself and  reply `unsubscribe` MC still opts me out.

Does anyone know why this is? Is it a bug?

I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238585/disable-reply-email-management-feature) post where someone suggested setting DNS Record Redirect = No, which has worked but will then stop my auto replies from working which I want to retain.